# Ordenar un array de objetos con el método de Inserción

Tags: java

Esta es mi clase estudiante

```java
class Estudiante
{
        private String carnet;
        private String nombre;
        private String apellidos;
        private int notaAdmision;
    
        public Estudiante() {
    
        }// Constructor default
    
        public Estudiante(String carnet, String nombre, String apellidos, int notaAdmision) {
            this.carnet = carnet;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellidos = apellidos;
            this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
        }// Constructor sobrecargado
    
        public String getCarnet() {
            return this.carnet;
        }
    
        public String getNombre() {
            return this.nombre;
        }
    
        public String getApellidos() {
            return this.apellidos;
        }
    
        public int getNotaAdmision() {
            return this.notaAdmision;
        }
    
        public void setCarnet(String carnet) {
            this.carnet = carnet;
        }
    
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
    
        public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
            this.apellidos = apellidos;
        }
    
        public void setNotaAdmision(int notaAdmision) {
            this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
        }
    
        
        public String toString() {
            return "Estudiante: carnet=" + this.carnet + ", nombre=" + this.nombre + ", apellidos=" + this.apellidos + ", notaAdmision="
                    + this.notaAdmision ;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el `main` donde tengo el
`arregloEstudiante` de tamaño `10`. Tiene varios atributos y debo ordenarlo alfabéticamente usando el 2do y 3ro que serían nombre y apellidos, usando el método de ordenamiento por inserción.

```
    Estudiante[] arregloEstudiante = new Estudiante[10];

    arregloEstudiante[0] = new Estudiante("C54411", "Maria", "Mora Mora", 700);
    arregloEstudiante[1] = new Estudiante("B92542", "Jose", "Solano Solano", 444);
    arregloEstudiante[2] = new Estudiante("C42214", "Alonso", "Solano Mora", 800);
    arregloEstudiante[3] = new Estudiante("A95720", "Miguel", "Mora Solano", 550);
    arregloEstudiante[4] = new Estudiante("B32567", "Andrea", "Jimenez Ureña", 625);
    arregloEstudiante[5] = new Estudiante("C34767", "Fabian", "Sanchez Alvarado", 740);
    arregloEstudiante[6] = new Estudiante("C72588", "Martin", "Moya Ureña", 592);
    arregloEstudiante[7] = new Estudiante("B42667", "Fabiana", "Sanchez Alvarado", 689);
    arregloEstudiante[8] = new Estudiante("A22523", "Mariano", "Mora Mora", 750);
    arregloEstudiante[9] = new Estudiante("B4562", "Alonso", "Solano Morales", 497);
```

Este es mi método de ordenamiento por inserción. Uso JAVA 1.8 para compilar y les adjunto todo lo que hice:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arregloEstudiante.length; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            String clave = arregloEstudiante[j].getNombre() + arregloEstudiante[i].getApellidos();
            for (j = i - 1; j > 0 && clave
                    .compareTo(arregloEstudiante[i].getNombre() + arregloEstudiante[i].getApellidos()) < 0; j--) {
                arregloEstudiante[j + 1] = arregloEstudiante[j];
            } // For
            String auxiliar = String.valueOf(arregloEstudiante[j + 1]);
            auxiliar = clave;
        } // For Grande
```

Solo llego a respuestas repetidas en las que me da los mismos 3 nombres varias veces y no los 10 ordenados. Ocupo acomodar esos 10 nombres por orden alfabético usando nombre y apellido.

El resultado que he obtenido es este.

```
Lista por Nombre y Apellido
Maria Mora Mora
Jose Solano Solano
Alonso Solano Mora
Alonso Solano Mora
Andrea Jimenez Ureña
Fabian Sanchez Alvarado
Fabian Sanchez Alvarado
Fabiana Sanchez Alvarado
Fabiana Sanchez Alvarado
Alonso Solano Morales
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hagamos una retroalimentación..**

El algoritmo de inserción se basa en:

- Encontrar una clave en cada iteración (esto se lo hace en el bucle principal).
- Luego, se pasa a ejecutar un bucle anidado, donde su condición de salida sólo será falsa en estos casos:

  - Sí se encuentra un elemento que sea menor a la clave (aquí se debe tener en cuenta que solo comparamos elementos que estén a la izquierda de la clave).
  - Sí se llega a un índice negativo (por eso la condición debe ser `j >= 0`).
- Sí la condición de salida del bucle anidado da como resultado `true`, entonces, pasamos a desplazar el elemento hacia la derecha.
- Cuando el bucle anidado finalice, pues se debe asignar la clave en la posición que se haya encontrado para colocar dicho elemento.

En código Java quedaría así:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < arregloEstudiante.length; i++)
{
    int j;
    //Encontramos la clave (además "clave" es la variable auxiliar)..
    Estudiante clave = arregloEstudiante[i];
    //Obtenemos el nombre completo de la clave..
    String nombre_completo = clave.getNombre() + clave.getApellidos();
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && nombre_completo.compareTo(arregloEstudiante[j].getNombre() + arregloEstudiante[j].getApellidos()) < 0; j--) 
        //Desplazamos el elemento hacia la derecha..
        arregloEstudiante[j + 1] = arregloEstudiante[j];
    //Asignamos la clave en la posición encontrada..
    arregloEstudiante[j + 1] = clave;
}
```

**Nota:** El algoritmo ordena de menor a mayor.

**El resultado en pantalla debería ser:**

```java
Estudiante: carnet=C42214, nombre=Alonso, apellidos=Solano Mora, notaAdmision=800
Estudiante: carnet=B4562, nombre=Alonso, apellidos=Solano Morales, notaAdmision=497
Estudiante: carnet=B32567, nombre=Andrea, apellidos=Jimenez Ureña, notaAdmision=625
Estudiante: carnet=C34767, nombre=Fabian, apellidos=Sanchez Alvarado, notaAdmision=740
Estudiante: carnet=B42667, nombre=Fabiana, apellidos=Sanchez Alvarado, notaAdmision=689
Estudiante: carnet=B92542, nombre=Jose, apellidos=Solano Solano, notaAdmision=444
Estudiante: carnet=C54411, nombre=Maria, apellidos=Mora Mora, notaAdmision=700
Estudiante: carnet=A22523, nombre=Mariano, apellidos=Mora Mora, notaAdmision=750
Estudiante: carnet=C72588, nombre=Martin, apellidos=Moya Ureña, notaAdmision=592
Estudiante: carnet=A95720, nombre=Miguel, apellidos=Mora Solano, notaAdmision=550
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** Estás asignando mal la clave, puesto que usas la variable `j` en vez de `i`:

```java
String clave = arregloEstudiante[j].getNombre() + arregloEstudiante[i].getApellidos();
```

Debería ser:

```java
String clave = arregloEstudiante[i].getNombre() + arregloEstudiante[i].getApellidos();
```

**Nota:** La clave está asociada con la variable `i`, en cambio, `j` con los elementos que estén a la izquierda de la clave.

**2.-** El primer elemento si se toma en cuenta, por lo tanto, está condición:

```java
j > 0
```

Debe ser cambiada a:

```java
j >= 0
```

**3.-** En ningún momento asignas la clave en la posición encontrada:

```java
String auxiliar = String.valueOf(arregloEstudiante[j + 1]);
auxiliar = clave;
```

Básicamente ese código no tiene ningún sentido. Aquí lo se debe hacer es asignar la clave en la posición `j + 1`:

```java
arregloEstudiante[j + 1] = clave;
```

¿Por qué debe ser `j + 1`? Pues hay la posibilidad de que `j` termine con un valor negativo, así que se debe evitar una posible excepción (como `ArrayIndexOutBounds`). Además, de esto depende que el algoritmo funcione correctamente.

**OJO:** La clave en este caso debe ser la **referencia del objeto** que esté en `X` posición del array (acuérdate que el array guarda referencias a objetos de tipo `Estudiante`) y deberá estar guardada en una variable auxiliar para no perder la referencia.

Teniendo claro estas observaciones, ya podemos comprender porque tu código no funcionaba.

De igual manera, podríamos optimizar la implementación, puesto que en cada iteración concatenas dos objetos de tipo `String` para poder generar el nombre completo.

Así que lo recomendable es crear un atributo adicional en la clase `Estudiante` denominado `nombre_completo` y ahí almacenas directamente el nombre + el apellido.

Obviamente, debes definir el setter (se podría llamar `setNombreCompleto`) y getter (`getNombreCompleto`) para dicho atributo y además concatenar directamente en el constructor de la clase:

```java
public Estudiante(String carnet, String nombre, String apellidos, int notaAdmision) 
{
        this.carnet = carnet;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
        nombre_completo = nombre + apellidos;
}
```

Entonces, el código ahora quedaría así:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < arregloEstudiante.length; i++)
{
    int j;
    Estudiante clave = arregloEstudiante[i];
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && clave.getNombreCompleto().compareTo(arregloEstudiante[j].getNombreCompleto()) < 0; j--) 
        arregloEstudiante[j + 1] = arregloEstudiante[j];
    arregloEstudiante[j + 1] = clave;
}
```

**Nota:** El resultado en pantalla es el mismo que el anterior.

**Fuente:**

[Ordenamiento por inserción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_inserci%C3%B3n).

Comment: Wow muchísimas gracias, me hiciste comprender mejor como es que funciona este método de ordenamiento, me era complicado de comprender al inicio pero ahora con la retro alimentación y las observaciones salió todo solo muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score -2):

¿Ya probaste así?

```
Estudiante[] arregloEstudiante = new Estudiante[10];
arregloEstudiante[0] = new Estudiante("C54411", "Maria", "Mora Mora", 700);
...
```

Luego la ordenas:

```
Collections.sort(arregloEstudiante);
```

Y la imprimes:

```
for (String orden : arregloEstudiante) {
   System.out.println(orden);
}
```

Comment: Tengo que usar el método de ordenación de Inserción. no puedo usar el sort. ni ninguna otra función solo el método de ordenamiento por inserción